# Button on click event disable button after 5 times it was clicked

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, button, onclick

I am fairly new to VB.NET. I feel like I did the hard parts and struggling with the easy one! I googled it before coming here but still struggling.

Basically I have a drop down list with all the available treatments and button next to it ( Add treatment). Every time I choose treatment from list I click on the button and it add it then bind it to gridview, the only issue is I want users to be able to add up to 5 treatments then disable the button. The question how Can I say find the number of times the button was clicked then I suppose I can just put If statement, I dont know how to find the value of the number of times the button was clicked.

```
 Dim availableTreatment As ListItem = New ListItem
    Dim count As Integer = 0
    For count = 0 To 4
        If count <= 4 And btnavailableTreatment ( button clicked value is what should go here)  Then
            availableTreatment = DDTreatmentList.SelectedItem
            c.name = availableTreatment.Value
           saveTreatment(c)
            gvavailableTreatment.DataSource = getTreatment(c.name)
            gvavailableTreatment.DataBind()

        Else
            btnavailableTreatment.Enabled = False
        End If
        count = count + 1
    Next
```

Comment: If that code is within the `Button_Click` event then the counter is being reset to 0 ever time the button is pressed. Try moving the counter outside the Button_Click.

Comment: @DaveB Simply moving it outside won't fix it either. Instances of the page class are lost and then recreated with each postback. He will need to store the data in the form, such as ViewState or a hidden field.

Comment: mason, She*. I will try and store it in hidden field and see how it goes! Cheers

Comment: Its not easy question after all! could you illustrate it with an example please?

Comment: My apologies on mixing up your gender. I'll work on an answer for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this markup to your page:

```
<asp:HiddenField id="NumberOfTimesClickedHiddenField"
                 value="0" 
                 runat="server"/>
```

Add this to your button click handler

```
'get previous value
Dim numberOfTimesClicked = Integer.Parse(NumberOfTimesClickedHiddenField.Value)

'increment value
numberOfTimesClicked += 1

'store new value
NumberOfTimesClickedHiddenField.Value = numberOfTimesClicked.ToString()

If numberOfTimesClicked >= 5 Then
    btnavailableTreatment.Enabled = False
End If
```

Now the value will be persisted in the form data on the page.

I originally wrote this in C#, and I'm not a VB.NET programmer so I used a translator to convert it. There may be syntax errors but the general flow should be correct.

Comment: I think yours would work but I am stuck with incrementing the value of the hidden field. it is throwing an error!

Comment: For the increment value : it says you can not convert Double to Hidden Field so I did .. numberOfTimesClicked.value += 1 instead  Then for storing new Value // NumberOfTimesClickedHiddenField.Value = numberOfTimesClicked.ToString() .. It is not updating the hidden field so every time I click it starts from 0!!!

Comment: You didn't name your variables the same as me, that's why you got that error. Notice I named the hidden field `NumberOfTimesClickedHiddenField`, not `numberOfTimesClicked`.

Comment: I changed naming however it says String can not be converted to Hidden Field

Comment: You're going to have to double check your variable names. Look at my answer. `NumberOfTimesClickedHiddenField` should be a HiddenField. `numberOfTimesClicked` should be an Integer. Do you see the line where I store the new value? Double check you did it like I did.

Comment: I think its doing what I asked for, I have other issue should figure out on my own! Many Thanks :D